# Meaning of lag of macro variable (e.g. GDP)

Tags: finance, economics

What does it mean to lag a macro variable such as GDP? (To put it in a context, just ctrl+F "lag" in this paper for example; http://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1486524&fileOId=1647104 ) The author is for example speaking about lagging indicators without defining the meaning of it.

For example if I have a time-series of GDP values and then lag it by 1 quarter. Does it mean that the values should be shifted backwards or forwards in time? Which one of 1) and 2)?

| Time | GDP reported | 1) GDP 1 quarter lag | 2) GDP 1 quarter lag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018Q1 | 500 | - | 600 |
| 2018Q2 | 600 | 500 | 450 |
| 2018Q3 | 450 | 600 | 490 |
| 2018Q4 | 490 | 450 | 310 |
| 2019Q1 | 310 | 490 | - |

Comment: It means ***1) GDP 1 quarter lag***. It means , for example, that you explain something at time ***t*** by somthing at time ***t-1***, e.g. ***GDP(t) ~ function(..., GDP(t-1))***.

Comment: Why? It does not make sense. For me it makes more sense to shift it back since in reality it would take time to publish the GDP value, so it would in theory be known before it is being reported. Could you perhaps motivate it.

Comment: For example, imagine that we only have one variable in hand, GDP. Say that  we currently are at time ***t*** and want to predict the next quarter GDP at ***t+1***. Put differently, we would write  ***GDP(t + 1) ~ unknown_function(GDP(t))***. Using the data you show, this would be equivalent to training a model with: ***500*** to explain ***600***; ***600*** to explain ***450***; ***450*** to explain ***490***; ***450*** to explain ***310***... Such specification is called [autoregressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model), among many others.

Comment: Figured or what ?

Comment: It just feels a bit weird then, because say for example in an economic crisis then corporates might default more frequent which would at a later stage in time reflect in a worsened GDP. So it does not make sense shifting the GDP forwards in time to align with the time series of for example default frequencies. Or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Yup, you are thinking wrong. The economic relationship may be doubtful, but not the shifting process. Also, forward... backward... it all depends on your point of view... Are you looking at things from that of the endogenous quantity... or from the point of view of the exogenous one... (?)

Answer (score 0):

Lag are in the past. In that case 2.

Usually you could advanced or lagged indicator one a variables "happens" before or after another.

For example you usually wants to have a good understanding of the GDP. For usually you have variables that trend to behave in advance with regards GDP or with some lag.

Also could depend or their availability. See Tabe 1 from Camacho and Perez-Quiros 2010

References:

- Greene, W. H. (2000). Econometric analysis 4th edition. International edition, New Jersey: Prentice Hall, 201-215. As in https://spu.fem.uniag.sk/cvicenia/ksov/obtulovic/Mana%C5%BE.%20%C5%A1tatistika%20a%20ekonometria/EconometricsGREENE.pdf
- Camacho, M., & Perez‐Quiros, G. (2010). Introducing the euro‐sting: Short‐term indicator of euro area growth. Journal of Applied Econometrics, 25(4), 663-694. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1127162

In particular "The generally accepted reference series to anticipate short-term economic developments
is the Euro area GDP growth rate. However, the “final” estimates of GDP growth, the
so called second release, is published with a delay of about 14 weeks after the end of
the respective quarter. Given this publication delay, forecasters and researchers try to
identify the current economic developments by using indicators which are more timely
available although exhibit similar economic fluctuations than the reference series. Natural
indicators are the two early announcements of the second release which are called flash
and first releases, respectively. Other candidates are monthly indicators which are based
on either economic activity data (hard indicators) or surveys (soft indicators) since they
exhibit much shorter publishing delay than the second releases".